# running two python scripts on boot on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have a python scripts (Duploadr.py) that runs continues, basically it monitors the folder for any changes.
And I have a tkinter program (tk.py).

> I need to run both after Raspberry pi in a GUI interface.

the first script need to be run under a certain folder so I have to cd /foldername/Duploadr.py before I executed

All files have execute and all using chmod.

not I create a file called launcher.sh and addeded to

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
I added this to the bottom
@sh /home/pi/launcher.sh
```

in launcher.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/tk.py
cd /home/pi/Flickr/
sudo python /home/pi/Flickr/Duploadr.py -d &
```

what is happening the launcher is executing fine, but it is only execute the first script and it ignores the second one.

I tried to change the sequence but no matter what I do, it does not execute the second sudo.

when I do

ps -aux | grep python
root      1148  0.2  0.4   7232  3368 ?        S    10:52   0:00 sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/tk.py
root      1156 15.3  3.0  40280 23588 ?        Sl   10:52   0:01 python3 /home/pi/Desktop/tk.py
pi        1291  0.0  0.0   4376   548 pts/0    S+   10:52   0:00 grep --color=auto python

I do not see the second one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append `&` to the end of your first command, like so:

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/tk.py &
```

Comment: They both need the `&`